# Get notification data when opening an app

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

When my app receives a push notification I can click on it and I can receive its data from the activity's `intent.extras` in my Fragment.

However when I receive a push notification and click on the app icon instead (with the notification badge) - it doesn't hold `intent.extras`.

So if I perform the latter, how can I access the data from the notification (such a `title`, `body`) etc?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56231468/7254873

Answer (score 3):

try this
        getIntent().getExtras().getString("s");

Comment: No intent data is coming through to my activity when I open the app by clicking on the app icon. Intent data only comes through when I click on the push notification.

Comment: According to docs, if you want to process background message arrival, you have to send 'click_action' with your message. But it is not possible if you send message from Firebase console, only via Firebase API. It means you will have to build your own "console" in order to enable marketing people to use it. So, this makes Firebase console also quite useless!